# How to sync slash command globally discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to sync all slash commands with all guilds in discord.py

My code

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands



intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)




tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)




@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    try:        
        await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=11234411))

        print(f'Synced')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



@tree.command(name="ping", description="Simple ping pong command", guild=discord.Object(id=1032007648566059142))
async def ping(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Pong", ephemeral=True)
```

I tried to just delete the guild=discord.Object(id=11234411) But its not working

Comment: Keep in mind that if you sync slash commands globally, it takes up to an hour for them to show up.

Comment: 1. Don't sync in `on_ready`. Auto-syncing is bad & will get you ratelimited (the limits are very strict). Use a regular message command to do it. | 2. Removing the `guild` argument to `sync()` should do the trick, it might take a little while for the changes to take effect. `sync()` returns the commands that it synced, so you can print the output of that to see if it worked or not.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't sync your commands in `on_ready` because it's unnecessary and can get you ratelimited. You should create a owner-only command to sync the command tree instead.

```py
@tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')
async def sync(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user.id == YOUR_ID:
        await tree.sync()
        print('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('You must be the owner to use this command!')
```

You don't need to include `guild` anywhere because you're syncing global commands. Your extra saftey/security you can create a message command instead.

Comment: Wait but, how does one sync that command then? Is there a way to run commands without syncing?

Comment: @ThomasRosebrough You can, but you sync locally which will show instantaneously. There's a few ways to go about it, the way I use is to decorate the cog with the guild id that you want to test in. Then, locally sync using guild id. 

decoration above the cog 
`@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = guild_id))`

command to run 
`await self.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by instead of defining a client, I used a bot, which is just an extension of client and can execute both slash command and regular command. You don't have to import app_commands for it.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents,
                   case_insensitive=False,)
```

I define my slash command in the following way:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="match", description="looking for a match")
async def match(interaction, arg1: str):
***rest of the code***
```

I define my regular command for syncing as follows:

```
@bot.command()
async def sync(ctx):
    print("sync command")
    if ctx.author.id == OWNER_USERID:
        await bot.tree.sync()
        await ctx.send('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You must be the owner to use this command!')
```

You can now call the regular "/sync" command to sync the slash commands. Be careful, if you also have on_message event then add `await bot.process_commands(message)`. This is because, by default, the on_message event blocks command processing, and if you want to process the message as a command, you need to use that block of code.