# how to sync slash commands globally

Tags: discord.py

in my on_ready i had `synced = await bot.tree.sync()` and it would sync them but i was told i could get rate limited for that

```py
@bot.tree.command(name='sync', description='Owner only')
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(ctx:discord.Interaction):
    if interaction.user.id == 616438322864193553:
        await bot.tree.sync()
        print('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message('You must be the owner to use this command!')
```

i have this for my command but get an error

[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppaji.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sync slash command globally discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413367/how-to-sync-slash-command-globally-discord-py)

Comment: i think i got it 

`
@bot.tree.command(name="sync", description = "hi")
@commands.is_owner()
async def sync(ctx):
    print("sync command")
    await bot.tree.sync()
    await ctx.response.send_message('Command tree synced.')
`

done this but how can I get it to tell me how many commands were synced

Comment: never mind i made a test command called `hey` and tried the sync command and it says command tree synced but when I try `/hey` it don't pop up @zurgeg

Comment: The error says that `interaction` is not defined. Simply put, you used `interaction` when you set `discord.Interaction` to `ctx` when defining the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sync you application command in a good manner, you need to sync it manually by yourself in a message command.
Example Code,

```py
# manually sync all global commands if necessary
@bot.command(description="sync all global commands")
@commands.is_owner()
async def syncslash(ctx: commands.Context):
  if ctx.author.id == BOTOWNERID:
    try:
      await bot.tree.sync()
      print("Synced")
    except discord.Forbidden:
      await ctx.send("Unexpected forbidden from application scope.")
  else:
    await ctx.send("You must be the owner to use this command")
```

Also, please consider removing the decorator `commands.is_owner()` or `if ctx.author.id == BOTOWNERID` since this is redundant. One of them will do the work.

Comment: i tried this and it wont do anything